# Land Cover Dataset

Tags: google-maps, maps, gis, openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm interested in implementing some data visualizations as map layers. But I'm interested in generating data layers only above land area (land cover). A good example would be to plot population density over a coastal city. What is a good approach for this, when it comes to the data source and how to actually display layers with such detailed boundaries?

Technically, so far I'm using Leaflet.js and tiles based on OpenStreetMaps, but the question is not necessary technology specific. Also, I'm not interested in plotting this for the whole planet, but for areas of a few hundreds square kilometers (for e.g. a coastal city).

To better give an idea of what I'm interested in, [this Koordinates](https://koordinates.com/x/qg9iW6) map is something that is similar to what I'm interested in. However, I need something a bit more detailed on the borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need a desktop or server based GIS such coverage, but not JS to do the processing on the client side.

How you do the mapping (here: linking statistical data and land areas) depends on your data itself. You can load OSM based shape files into QGIS and do some python scripting or using the PostGIS commands to link your data and choose a map style.

Another idea would be http://geocommons.com that allow easy visualization if you upload CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your area of interest, you can obtain some highly detailed shapefiles from numerous sources.  Especially if the local area provides GIS data to the public (many larger coastal cities do, e.g. [New York](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwndistricts.shtml), [London](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page)).  From there, you can create a GeoJSON text of the geometries ([here's a **free** tool](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) for that).  Parsing the JSON is very simple and it's very easy to add it to [leaflet maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html).  You can even get creative and add more keys to each geometry object with the data you want to visualize.